# How do I install VIZ

Tags: python-3.x

I want to install Python library `Viz` from https://pypi.org/project/viz/#description.

But when I try to install it, I obtain the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can´t decode byte 0x81 in position 680`
Any idea about how could fix that error?

Thanks in advance